# Delete Multiple Pages when deactivate a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I already create multiple pages for plugin activation,
But I cannot delete multiple pages for Deactivation.

This is my code

```
function my_plugin_remove() 

//  the id of our page..

{
$pageid_main = get_option( 'hclpage', $valuemain );
$pageid_budget = get_option ('hclpage', $budgetvalue);
$pageid_viewbudget = get_option ('hclpage', $valueviewbudget);


wp_delete_post( $pageid_main, true ); // this will trash, not delete
wp_delete_post( $pageid_budget, true );
wp_delete_post( $pageid_viewbudget, true );
}
```

what is 'hclpage' option?
Its only return 1 postid (the last pages i create when plugin activation), so my function only delete 1 pages, but cannot multiple pages.

Comment: Indeed, what **is** hlcpage? If this is *your* code, then you should know what it is.  (In this case, that is the "key" for the option you are storing in the `wp_options` table.  My question is, why do you have a variable afterwards? See the docs on [get_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

Comment: @cale_b i got it mixed up with update_option, im using 'hclpage' because following someone advice, now i understand that the "key' can be changed as i wish. I thought i must use wordpress option preference as the parameter.

Comment: OK - is there still a question, or did you work it out? IF there IS still a question, please edit your question to clarify.  If there is NOT a  question, please kindly delete it.